# How to turn raw string to `bs4.element.Tag`

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

How can I turn raw string: `

```
string = "<p color="#000000" font_size="11">Sample Text</p>"`
```

into a beautiful soup tag? `bs4.element.Tag`

Thanks.

Comment: can you add the source and also the code you're trying with.

Comment: it's just a string, string = "<p color="#000000" font_size="11">Sample Text</p>"` And I want to convert it back into a beautiful soup tag, type is bs4.element.Tag

Comment: did you try `BeautifulSoup(string, "html.parser")` ?

Comment: code that you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use BeautifulSoup on the string:

```
string = '<p color="000000" font_size=11>Sample Text</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(string)

In: soup.find('p')
Out: <p color="000000" font_size="11">Sample Text</p>

In: type(soup.find('p'))
Out: bs4.element.Tag
```

Comment: Thanks, that was obvious and great.